# $\liminf $ and $\sup $ inequality

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

It is clear to me that $\liminf X_n \le \limsup X_n$ but every time that I see that $\liminf X_n \le \sup X_n$ it sound to me not so obvious awkward. Could someone help me to understand this inequality?$ $ $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it clear from the definition? Limsup is less than equal to sup.

Proof:

The definition of limsup is the following:
Inf{sup$(T_n)$} where $T_n$ is the $n$th tail of the sequence $x_n$.  Clearly, sup$(T_n)$ is less than equal to sup($x_n$). Now, just take infimum over $n$. Then we get that limsup$x_n$ $\leq$ sup$x_n$.

By the way, the definition of $T_n$ is {$x_k|  k\geq n$}.

Comment: But sup($T_n$) is a function of n, how could you say that is $\le$ than $sup(x_n)$

Comment: $T_n$ is a subset {$x_n$}. You're taking supremum on a smaller set.

Comment: but for example if $x_n=1/n$ then $sup(x_n)=1$ and $sup(T_n)=1/n$. isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. That's correct. Why "but"?

Comment: In your example, limsup$x_n$ is $0$ and sup{$x_n$} is $1$. So, we're good.

Comment: Another cool thing to notice:  define $y_n$ = sup$T_n$. Please observe that $y_n$ is a monotone (decreasing) sequence. Hence, the limit of $y_n$ is equal to inf{$y_n$}= inf{sup$T_n$}. Therefore, limsup is also  limit some  monotone sequence, which is also true for liminf. In that case, you get an increasing sequence. I believe this is one of the motivations to define limsup and liminf.

Comment: I said  "but" because in your answer you said: $sup(T_n) \le sup(x_n)$ maybe now I understood what you meant: that whatever n you chose in $sup(T_n)$ it will alway be $\le$ than $sup(x_n)$

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

As $\limsup X_n \le \sup X_n$, this second inequality $\liminf X_n \le \sup X_n$ should be obvious to you if $\liminf X_n \le \limsup X_n$ is.

So you're left to prove and think why $\limsup X_n \le \sup X_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\sup X_n$ is an upperbound of the set $\{X_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ which means that for **every** $k\in\mathbb N$ we have $X_k\leq\sup X_n$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, 
$$\limsup X_n=\lim_k\Bigl(\sup_{n\ge k} X_n\Bigr), $$
and the  sequence $(S_k)=\bigl(\sup_{n\ge k} X_n\bigr)_k$ is *non-increasing*, so
$$\liminf X_n\le\limsup X_n\le S_1=\sup X_n.$$